# Issue with Django service worker: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: django, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

EDIT 16/02/2021

project architecture (docker/nginx)

```
- dockercompose.yml
- app
    - core
    - app1 (many Django apps with similar archtiecture)
        - static
            - app1
                - js
                    - script.js
    - static
        - css
        - images
        - js
            - jquery.formset.js
            - manifest.json
    - templates
        - layout
            - base.html
            ...
        - home.html
        - offline.html
        ...
        - serviceworker.js
    - Dockerfile
- nginx
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Intense TBM",
    "short_name": "itbm",
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#FFF",
    "theme_color": "#493174",
    "description": "Randomization app rescue for Intnse TBM trial ANRS 12398",
    "dir": "ltr",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/static/images/intensetbm.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "160x160"
        },
        {
            "src": "/static/images/intensetbm.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "160x160"
        }
    ]
}
```

serviceworker.js

```
const VERSION = 'V1.0';

var staticCacheName = "intensetbm-pwa-v" + new Date().getTime();
var filesToCache = [
    '/offline/',
    '/static/css/styles.css'

];


self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    this.skipWaiting();
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            })
    )
});


self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName.startsWith("intensetbm-pwa-")))
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName !== staticCacheName))
                    .map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))
            );
        })
    );
});


self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(response => {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                return caches.match('/offline/');
            })
    )
});
```

---

EDIT 11/02/2021 19:00

It seems to be caused by include in my base.html

```
{% include 'layouts/_nav.html' %} 
{% include 'layouts/_footer.html' %}
```

---

I try to add service worker to my app.
But got an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

using debug tool, the first line <!doctype html> is underline for each files with error message
I coul not find anywhere explaination for that...

hope someone could help

[image]

Comment: The service worker is not configured correctly and is returning HTML for requests for JS/CSS files. It might be that those files are not cached and there is a default 404 response.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what do you mean by ```service worker is not configured correctly```? How can I check?

Comment: There are many different ways. A possible would would be a wildcard route that returns something like `offline.html` for all requests (including .js) that are not cached offline instead of just .html requests that are not cached. You'll have to include how the SW is configured.

Comment: @abraham thanks for replying, hope this will be more clear with architecture app and serviceworker.js file

Comment: In `install` you precache two requests, `fetch` will try to use the cache and then fallback to  using the network. When you are offline basically all requests will get the HTML for `offline` because nothing else cached. I'd recommend you check out `workbox`, it's makes working with service workers much easier.

Comment: I willl look for workbox. I just made a try so I just cache css... if I cache other files, it should solve my issue?